# C - "warning: format "%c" expects argument of type "char *", but argument 3 has type "int":?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pixel, ppm

I am writing code to read a PPM file into a struct pixel_type array containing 3 unsigned chars r,g, and b. The code that causes problems looks like this:

```
struct pixel_type pArray[width][height], *pPtr[width][height];
pPtr[width][height] = &pArray[width][height];

for(h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for(w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        fscanf(in, "%c%c%c", pPtr[w][h]->r, pPtr[w][h]->g, pPtr[w][h]->b);
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get this message for all 3 "%c"s:

warning:

```
format â%câ expects argument of type âchar *â, but argument (3,4, or 5) has type âintâ [-Wformat]
```

What would be the best way to read the pixel values into the struct pixel_type array?

```
struct pixel_type
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};
```

Comment: @Kaz I can add more of my code if you want. I'm not asking for anyone to code for me, I just need to know the best way to take each pixel value (I believe P6 PPM pixel values are stored in binary) and convert them to three chars (r, g, b). Then I can use this info to write a different PPM file.

Comment: @HighCore You're right, sorry. I kinda want to change it now. Next time.

Comment: @user2993631 ???? That comment was supposed to be for a completely different question by someone else, and does not apply here. How did that happen ... I'm pretty sure I was on the right question when I typed it. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one temporary pointer, not a whole array of them.

```
struct pixel_type {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
    };

main()
{   
    struct pixel_type pArray[10][10], *pPtr;
    int height = 10, width = 10, h, w;
    char buf[32];

    /* testing */

    strcpy(buf, "abc");

    for(h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        for (w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            pPtr = &pArray[width][height];
            /* testing */
            sscanf(buf, "%c%c%c", &pPtr->r, &pPtr->g, &pPtr->b);
            /* fscanf(in, "%c%c%c", &pPtr->r, &pPtr->g, &pPtr->b); */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that fixes it. My rep's too low to "vote up", but I appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need any temporary pointer at all. Just use `&pArray[width][height].r`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare a pointer to the array `*pPtr[width][height]`, since `pArray[width][height]` is already an array and this:

```
pArray[0][0];
```

is equivalent to this:

```
*pArray;
```

In the same way that this:

```
&pArray[0][0];
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
pArray;
```

So you just need to point the address of where your data is (inside of the structure), after the pointer or the array had already been deferenced.

```
struct pixel_type pArray[width][height];

for(h = 0; h < height; h++)
{
    for(w = 0; w < width; w++)
    {
        fscanf(in, "%c%c%c", &(pArray[w][h].r), &(pArray[w][h].g), &(pArray[w][h].b));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing your 2D array of pointers `pPtr[width][height]` to a pointer `pPtr` will solve your problem.